# How to reach child element within <a> element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a structure like this

```
 <ul>
  <li>
    <a>
     <img />
     <span />
    </a>
  </li>
  <li> 
    ......
  </li>
  <li> 
    ......
  </li>
 </ul>
```

I am using jquery like this#

```
            $("ul#someid").find("li:last > a[name="some.....]
```

How can i access the img element and the span element within the "a" element like above.

i am using now like this

```
  $("ul#pushedProducts").find("li:last > a[name= <%=PushedProductsParametersMapper.PARAMS_PRODUCTS_INFO%>]").children('span').attr({name:'<%=PushedProductsParametersMapper.PARAMS_PRODUCTS_INFO%>' + pushedProductsTypesCount, id:'<%=PushedProductsParametersMapper.PARAMS_PRODUCTS_INFO%>' + pushedProductsTypesCount , style :'display:none;'});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var $img = $("ul#someid").find('li:last > a[name="some....."]').children("img")
```

Take care about quotes next to `name`

Comment: what if the image and id field also has an id how to call with specific name?

Comment: you can keep on using selector. For instance: `var $img = $("ul#someid").find('li:last > a[name="some....."]').children('img[name="imgname"')`. Don't forget you can combinate selectors. Felix Kling showed you an example in his answer

Comment: @Saurabh: Any element with an ID can be selected with `$('#id')`. But don't forget that IDs are supposed to be unique.

Comment: and how can i change the attribte within image element for example image id

Comment: you can use [`.attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) >> `$(..).attr('id','mynewid');`

Comment: @Saurabh: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jquery+element+change+attribute ... The [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/) is good. Have a look at it and I'm sure you will find answers to most of your questions.

Comment: this is unreadable! Please edit your question or post a new one. And try to debug your code with firebug to see where it doesn't work.

Comment: a wrong selector won't raise an error but you can test statements in firebug to find the right one. Besides, `<%=PushedProductsParametersMapper.PARAMS_PRODUCTS_INFO%>` won't be interpreted in your js (or must be server generated)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to select both, you can use [`.children()` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/children/):

```
$("#someid").find("li:last > a[name=['someName']").children();
```

Otherwise, just use the [child selector *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) again, `a > b > c`,
or the [descendant selector *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/), `a > b c`.

You can combine the [selectors *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) however you want to.

Answer (score 0):

Asuming the A tag has an ID,

```
$('#id img')
```

and

```
$('#id span')
```

would be enough. Classes will work aswell using $('.class img') etc

Answer (score 0):

```
$("ul#someid li:first a[name='somename'] img")...
$("ul#someid li:first a[name='somename'] span")...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("ul#someid").find("li:last > a").children(); // will give you all children
$("ul#someid").find("li:last > a").find("img");
$("ul#someid").find("li:last > a").find("span");
```